# In Islam, is it permissible for a girl to be close friends with a boy?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I wonder whether two persons who are not married to each other have a right to be friends or even close friends? For example, was there any women friends of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) excluding His wives?

Comment: Islam always tell the truth....if anybody have male as a friends plz ask forgiveness to Allah.
Allah always forgive our sins...

Comment: Everything has limit, under Quran and Hadith 's limit, it's ok. Understanding of friendship and close relation is required. There are already fine answers available here.

Comment: By "who are not permissible to each other", do you mean They are not allowed to marry each other, like close relatives? I believe that changes whole meaning of the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Quran - Surah An-Nur [24:30]:](http://quran.com/24/30)

> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.

Hadith - Al-Tirmidhi 3118:

> Whenever a man is alone with a woman the Devil makes a third.

Hadith - Al-Tirmidhi

> Do not call on women in theabsence of their husbands, because Shaitan
>   mightbe circulating in you like blood circulates

Hadith - Fath-al-Qadir

> The one who touches the hand of a woman without having a lawful
>   relationwith her, will have an ember (hot coal) placed on hispalm on
>   the Day of Judgement

If you can **not**

- look at her (unless for marriage proposal)
- meet a woman without mahram
- shake hands with her
- be alone with her

then how is this friendship going to form?

As far as friendship on internet is concerned just reason logically about it. Would a husband appreciate that his wife has a 'close' male friend besides him? Or would a wife appreciate that when husband has a argument with her, he goes to his best friend to discuss the matter as opposed to making it up to her?

It leads to comparison between spouse as a friend and the close friend. This can cause problems in their married life. A friend who meets you only sometimes will always meet you with a smile (even on internet) but the spouse is living with you 24/7. There are more chances of conflicts and it requires patience and understanding to survive the relationship. This can be hard to understand when you can see the other opposite gender being nice to you while your spouse isn't as sweet most of the time.

Had it been permissible Sahaba's and Prophets would become friends with women. Prophet (P.B.U.H) did not have female friends and any of the Sahaba's did not have them. Neither did any other scholar of Islam had them. In Islam we look up to Quran, Sunnah, Sahaba and Scholars to learn how we should live our life.

One of the trick's of Shaitan is that he encourages you to do something that looks alright but would eventually lead to sin. Also bear in mind that if guardians are OK with a girl meeting and being friends with boys that doesn't make it halal in Islam. We need to be worried about what Allah wants from us and whether He is OK with it (not the lady her self or her parents).

Finally I'd recommend you to read this [fatwa for a girl who became friends with a guy](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/60269/thankful) and watch [Can Boys and Girls Be "Just Friends"?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWPJIFvcvaA)

Comment: Physical contact, or being alone with someone, is not required in (platonic) friendships. I have some very close friends that I met online that I have never seen with my own eyes.

Comment: Something to consider in your answer, no?

Comment: Just thought of something. What if they're single, and their guardian doesn't mind?

Comment: What's Fath Al-Qadir?

Comment: @ashes999 It is a hanafi book by Ibn Al Hammam

Comment: Can we mention that in the comments for people who don't know what it is?

Comment: say she is single - i have an intension of marrying her - when i speak to her (to know more about her) would i look down and talk? this is regarding your point `you can not look at her (since you're required to lower your gaze)`

Comment: @Ashu No, in that case you may look and examine. Exact question was asked by a sahabiyy.

Comment: @Ashu you should make your intention known if that's the case.

Answer (score -5):

Umer Ibn Khattab (Who the Shaitan was even afraid of) would not even be alone with a woman to teach her Quraan. Schollars say that you CANNOT be friends with a female. It's too dangerous